# How would you determine the value of $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, ratio

$$3a+2b = 4$$

$$\dfrac{1}{5a-2b} = \dfrac{2}{a+6b+5} = \dfrac{3}{c-4}$$

How would you determine the value of $c$?

Regards!

Comment: It is a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns. It can be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac { 1 }{ 5a-2b } =\frac { 2 }{ a+6b+5 } =\frac { 3 }{ c-4 } \Rightarrow \frac { 1+2 }{ 5a-2b+a+6b+5 } =\frac { 3 }{ c-4 } \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow \frac { 3 }{ 2\underset { 4 }{ \underbrace { \left( 3a+2b \right)  }  } +5 } =\frac { 3 }{ c-4 } \Rightarrow \frac { 3 }{ 13 } =\frac { 3 }{ c-4 } \Rightarrow c=17\\ \\ $$
Note that we have used here the property of the proportions:

> $$\frac { a }{ b } =\frac { c }{ d } =\frac { a\pm c }{ b\pm d } $$

Comment: could you give a reference link to the property of the proportions. Thnks.

Comment: You shouldn't need a link.  If $\frac{a}{b}= \frac{c}{d}$ then $ad= bc$.  $ad+ cd= bc+ cd$, d(a+ c)= c(b+ d) so that $\frac{a+ c}{b+ d}= \frac{c}{d}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
3a+2b &= 4
,\\
\frac{1}{5a-2b} &= 
\frac{2}{a+6b+5} = \frac{3}{c-4}
.
\end{align}

This system is equivalent to the linear $4\times4$ system
(assuming $5a-2b\ne0$, $a+6b+5\ne0$, $c\ne4$):

\begin{align}
3a+2b &= 4
,\\
5a-2b-d&=0
,\\
\tfrac12a+3b-d&=-\tfrac52
,\\
\tfrac13c-d&=\tfrac43
.
\end{align}

which has a solution
\begin{align}
a &= \tfrac{25}{24}
,\\ 
b &= \tfrac{7}{16}
,\\
c &= 17
,\\ 
d &= \tfrac{13}{3}
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

Aforenamed system of equations can be presented in matrix form as follows.

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & \phantom{-}2 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
5 &           -2 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & \phantom{-}6 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & \phantom{-}0 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}4 \\ 
\phantom{-}0 \\ 
-5 \\ 
\phantom{-}4
\end{bmatrix}
,
\end{align}

And one way of solving it is by using Gauss elimination

$[2]\ \to\ -2\times[2]+[3]$ to eliminate $A_{24}$

\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phantom{-}3 & 2 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  -9 & 10 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  \phantom{-}1 & 6 & 0 & -2 \\
  \phantom{-}0 & 0 & 1 & -3
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c \\ d
 \end{bmatrix}
 &=
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phantom{-}4 \\ 
  -5 \\ 
  -5 \\ 
  \phantom{-}4
 \end{bmatrix}
 ,
\end{align}

$[2]\ \to\ [2]+3\times[1]$ to eliminate $A_{21}$

\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & 2 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  0 & 16 & 0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  1 & 6 & 0 & -2 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -3
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c \\ d
 \end{bmatrix}
 &=
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phantom{-}4 \\ 
  \phantom{-}7 \\ 
  -5 \\ 
  \phantom{-}4
 \end{bmatrix}
 .
\end{align}

It follows that $b=\tfrac7{16}$
and $a=\tfrac13(4-2\times\tfrac7{16})=\tfrac{25}{24}$,
$d=-\tfrac12(-5-\tfrac{25}{24}-6\times\tfrac7{16})=\tfrac{13}3$,
and finally, $c=4-(-3)\times\tfrac{13}3=17$.

Comment: @g-kov, could you provide details on how you solve system/matrix?

Comment: @ yW0K5o: see the update.

Comment: @g-kov, good solution.

Answer (score 0):

$3a+2b=4 (1)$

$\frac{1}{5a-2b}=\frac{2}{a+6b+5} (2)$

$\frac{2}{a+6b+5}=\frac{3}{c-4} (3)$

From (2)  $2(5a-2b)=a+6b+5$ => $10a-4b=a+6b+5$ => $9a=10b+5$ => $a=\frac{10b+5}{9} (4)$

Put (4) into (1) $3*\frac{10b+5}{9} +2b =4$ => $\frac{10b+5}{3} +2b =4$ =>
$\frac{10b+5 +6b}{3}=4$ => $16b+5=12$ => $b=\frac{7}{16} (5)$

Get $a$ by using (5) and (4) $a=\frac{10b+5}{9}=\frac{10*\frac{7}{16}+5}{9}=\frac{\frac{35}{8}+5}{9} = \frac{75}{72}=\frac{25}{24} (6)$

Calculate $a+6b+5$ by using (5) and (6)

$a+6b+5=\frac{25}{24}+6*\frac{7}{16}+5=\frac{25}{24}+\frac{21}{8}+5=\frac{25+63+120}{24}=\frac{208}{24}=\frac{26}{3} (7)$

Put (7) to (3)

$\frac{2}{a+6b+5}=\frac{3}{c-4}$ => $2(c-4)=3*\frac{26}{3}$ =>
$2(c-4)=26$ => $c=13+4=17$

Thanks to NickD for finding my mistake.

Comment: When getting $a$ from (5) and (4), you forgot to multiply $b$ by 10.